# aws lambda: how to get console.log logs from real request (not test)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch

I've read this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html and made this lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    // const response = {
    //     statusCode: 200,
    //     body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    // };
    console.log(123321);
    console.log(event.Records[0].cf.response);
    console.log(event.Records[0].cf.request);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.Records[0].cf));
    console.log(event);
    console.log(arguments);

    //Get contents of response
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    //Return modified response

    return response;
};
```

It works (logs sends to CloudWatch) when I use "test" with fake model, but when I add CloudFront trigger and send request logs isn't send to any CloudWatch.

[image: Lambda function configuration]

1. how to get real (from production) `event` object from lambda
2. how to send/get logs from lambda which triggers by CloudFront?

Comment: Is your lambda getting called at all? I mean, do you see your other console.logs in CloudWatch when you are using CloudFront?

Comment: @TenorFlyy, yes it called, because I see response in url `xxx.cloudfront.net/test1.html`. And I don't have any logs by calling it not with "Test" button.

Comment: No, I mean when it is behind CloudFront, does it get called then. I understand it is getting called when testing.

Comment: @TenorFlyy now to check it?

Comment: When you try to call the lambda through CloudFront, it should log something, if it doesn't, then it isn't even being called. In order to make it easier and clear for debugging, change the code, e.g. add another `console.log` and save it, so next time your lambda gets called it will create new CloudWatch Log Stream. If no stream is created, then lambda wasn't called.

Comment: @TenorFlyy yes, `CloudWatch Log Stream` is not created. But lambda was called because it adds custom header to HTTP Response and this header was added (Cache-control with my custom time)! And if I create lambda with "error" its change answer: http://s3.micp.ru/Y3SSk.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183953/discussion-between-mixeroid-and-tenorflyy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Lambda being triggered by CloudFront, it now becomes a Lambda@Edge, so the CloudWatch Log streams are created in the region where the Lambda instance is called(that's decided by CloudFront).

So following the [AWS Lambda@Edge Docs for Troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-testing-debugging.html), the specific region could be easily determined with the provided shell script.

You can switch the region using dropdown at the header:
[image]